# Namespaced modules and Rails 3.1.3 autoload_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having some trouble to namespace a module that I include in a model.

in /app/models/car.rb

```
class Car
 include Search::Car
end
```

in /lib/search/car.rb

```
module Search
  module Car
    include ActiveSupport::Concern
    # methods in here
  end
end
```

in /config/application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/search/*"]
```

The weird thing is that I don't get any errors directly when I fire up the server. 
But if I refresh the browser after a while I get this error:

```
Expected #{Rails.root}/lib/search/car.rb to define Car
```

The nature of the problem indicates that it has something to do with:

/config/environments/development.rb

```
config.cache_classes = false
```

I also tried put a file `search.rb` directly in `/lib` where I define `Search`:

```
module Search
  # Put shared methods here
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Ok, turns out that if I rename `Search::Car` to `Search::CarSearch` it works.
Is it not possible to have Modules/Classes of the same name in a different scope?

Comment: You can have Modules/Classes of the same name in different scopes, but then when you are using the module Car methods, you should specify the scope, to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your comment. I thought so too but it doesn't seem to work. Any Idea why I get the error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is coming from your autoload_paths. `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]` will add all directories and their subdirectories under lib directory. meaning that you are telling rails to autoload lib/search/ directory, therefore car.rb under that directory is expected to define Car and not Search::Car. In order for rails to expect lib/search/car.rb to define Search::Car, you need to autoload lib/ directory and not lib/search. if you change you autoload to `config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/"]` and put search.rb in lib/ with following code:

```
module Search
  require 'search/car'
end
```

then rails will understand and expect lib/search/car.rb do define Search::Car and referencing Car module/class in other places of your code will not reference to this car.rb.

You should remove this line (you should only have autoload for lib directory):
`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/search/*"]`